# How do I insert additional criteria to my existing statistics algorithm?

Tags: javascript, math, statistics

### The Problem

I am writing a web app that will predict the winner of a baseball game. The user will select two teams, and based upon historical season data, my app will predict which team will win more games next season. Currently, the app uses the following data properties to calculate the number of games expected to win:

```
rs = runs scored
ra = runs allowed
g = number of games played total
actual = the real number of games won
```

[image: Win Algorithm]

**The Code**

```
var numGames = 162;
var runsScored = 901;
var runsAllowed = 828;

var numActual = 84;

function winsPredicted1(rs, ra, g, actual){
    var wins = ((.102*rs-0.103*ra)/g+.505)*g;
    var diff = wins - numActual;
    return { wins: wins, diff: diff }; // 88, 4
}
```

and so far so good. The formula is getting quite close...

```
 88.42800000000001
 4.4280000000000115
```

### Improving The Results

I now would like to add two more fields for the algorithm to consider:

1. Earned Run Average
2. Number of Base on Balls ( by this pitcher )

I am extremely new to statistical programming, and have researched this topic quite a bit. I cannot figure out how to add these new stats into the equation and have their values affect the result.

This project is for learning purposes only. Can anyone help me with these two new data fields?

Thank you! I am eager to see your suggestions.

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are running a linear regression model that includes an intercept (β<sub>0</sub>=0.505) and two regression coefficients (β<sub>1</sub>=0.102 and β<sub>2</sub>=0.103). Whereas the first regression coefficient refers to the number of runs scored per game (the more the better), the second refers to the number of runs allowed per game (the less the better).

To add more variables (often called "features" in Machine Learning) to the equation, you have to build a new linear regression (or other type of predictive) model. That is, you cannot just add these new features into the formula -- you need to train a model first to learn their importance.

There is a plethora of material out there on statistical modelling, so I'm not going to go into it here. I'd encourage you to take an online course or read a book on the basics of Supervised Machine Learning (which is essentially statistical modelling with the aim of making predictions). For instance, reading the first few chapters of *Introduction to Statistical Learning* by James, Witten, Hastie, and Tibshirani will most certainly get you started! The authors published a [free PDF](https://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/) of the book.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the coefficients 0.102 and 0.103 are already the results of a statistical regression. As I understand, you want to find the coefficients of next 2 features. If you want to add 2 more features then you must also observe the correlation between the "winning score" and those 2 features(They might not be even "linearly correlated"). Observe the graph for relation and create a model with all the features that you have.

At the end, you can have appropriate weights.